# ObjectMapper JSON with alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to Handle work with JSON response in Swift lang, I use 3 pod in my project : [`Alamofire`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) - [`ObjectMapper`](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/) - [`AlamofireObjectMapper`](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

And when http request send I want have JSON in my Object class. without trouble.
and here is my code.

**Contact.swift class:**

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Name: Mappable {
    var title: String!
    var first: String!
    var last: String!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["title"]
        first <- map["first"]
        last <- map["last"]
    }
}

class ContactsResponse: Mappable {
    var gender: String!
    var nameFull: [Name]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        gender <- map["gender"]
        nameFull <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift :**

```
let baseURL = "http://api.randomuser.me/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        makeHTTPRequest()
    }

    func makeHTTPRequest() {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, baseURL).responseObject { (response: Response<ContactsResponse, NSError>) in
            let contactResponse = response.result.value
            print(contactResponse?.gender) // print Nil :(
        }
    }
```

But when i build project print `nil` instead of Male or female for gender!

Whats wrong in my code?

Comment: did you found answer for this

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a delayed response but try checking your "keys" for a mistake. 
Narrow down on the source of your problem. So first check if response.result.value is giving you a response.

If i'm right, either response.result.value == nil or your mapping of the keys "gender" is wrong.

I'd recommend you to use if let statements instead of let.

so for example

```
if let contactResponse = response.result.value {
    print(contactResponse?.gender)
  } else {
     //Handle error
  }
```